# CircleCI failing for docker command not found

Tags: docker, maven, cicd, circleci

I am having a maven project previously built using bitbucket pipeline. I want to migrate it to circleCI. My config file looks like as follow

```yaml
version: 2.1
orbs:
  docker: circleci/docker@2.2.0 # Replace x.y.z with the latest version of the Docker orb

jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: maven:3.9.0-eclipse-temurin-17-focal

    steps:
      - checkout

      # You can customize this section according to your Maven build steps
      - run:
          name: Build
          command: mvn clean install -s settings.xml

      # No need to manually build the Docker image, use the existing Dockerfile
      - setup_remote_docker:
          version: 20.10.7
        # Use the following command to build and tag the Docker image
      - run:
          name: Build Docker Image
          command: |
            docker info
            docker build -t nexus:latest .
            docker tag nexus:latest kuldeepiitg/nexus:latest
            docker login -u $DOCKER_USERNAME -p $DOCKER_TOKEN
            docker push kuldeepiitg/nexus:latest

workflows:
  version: 2
  build-and-deploy:
    jobs:
      - build
```

But it is failing with following error.

```
#!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
docker info
docker build -t nexus:latest .
docker tag nexus:latest kuldeepiitg/nexus:latest
docker login -u $DOCKER_USERNAME -p $DOCKER_TOKEN
docker push kuldeepiitg/nexus:latest

/bin/bash: docker: command not found

Exited with code exit status 127
```

What should I change to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the documentation and came up with working elegant solution finally. I am also finding artifactId and version to build docker image.

```yaml
version: 2.1
orbs:
  docker: circleci/docker@2.2.0 # Replace x.y.z with the latest version of the Docker orb

jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: cimg/openjdk:17.0.7

    steps:
      - checkout

      # You can customize this section according to your Maven build steps
      - run:
          name: Build
          command: mvn clean install -s settings.xml

      # No need to manually build the Docker image, use the existing Dockerfile
      - setup_remote_docker:
          version: 20.10.7
          docker_layer_caching: true

        # Use the following command to build and tag the Docker image
      - run:
          name: Build Docker Image
          command: |
            export MVN_ARTIFACT_ID=$(mvn -q -Dexec.executable=echo -Dexec.args='${project.artifactId}' --non-recursive exec:exec)
            export MVN_PROJECT_VERSION=$(mvn -q -Dexec.executable=echo -Dexec.args='${project.version}' --non-recursive exec:exec)
            export IMAGE_NAME=kuldeepiitg/$MVN_ARTIFACT_ID:$MVN_PROJECT_VERSION
            echo "Building image ============== $IMAGE_NAME ==============="
            docker build -t $IMAGE_NAME --build-arg MVN_PROJECT_VERSION=$MVN_PROJECT_VERSION .
            docker login -u $DOCKER_USERNAME -p $DOCKER_TOKEN
            docker push $IMAGE_NAME

workflows:
  version: 2
  build-and-deploy:
    jobs:
      - build
```